# Dispatch overrides the full store in React Js

Tags: reactjs

I have an application what store data from inputs, from different components. Also, i'm using useReducer. When i make a dispatch `dispatch({type: "ADD_SONG", payload})`, my state from store is changing, from

```js
fruits: (1) [{…}]
people: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
new_fruit: {}
new_car: {}
song_list: (2) [{…}, {…},{…}]
new_song: {}
```

to:

```js
song_list: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

The code above i get in the console.
Actions creator:
`dispatch({type: "ADD_SONG", payload})`

Reducer:

```js
   case 'ADD_SONG': {
      return {
        ...state,
        new_song: {
          songId: payload.songId,
          name: payload.name,
        },
      }
    }
```

Why, when i dispatch, i override the full store? What could be the problem?

Comment: Add more code related to the reducer and action creators if you're using them.

Comment: Make sure to spread the state in reducer return
{
   ...state,
   song_list: action.payload
}

Answer (score 2):

This might be the problem:

In your reducer where you handle the state make sure you don't return new object that only has `song_list`.

You probably have something like this

```
const yourReducer = (state, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case 'SOMETYPE':
   return { song_list: action.payload };
 }
}
```

that should be

```
const yourReducer = (state, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case 'SOMETYPE':
   return { ...state, song_list: action.payload };
 }
}
```

Comment: @Asking where are you logging the state? Are you sure that's the only action that you're dispatching?

Comment: the rest of actions perfectly works, but when i dispatch the above, i get this

Comment: @Asking update the question with the entire reducer.

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```js
  case 'UPDATE_SONG_DATA':
      return {
        ...state,   //forgot to add the copy of state
        song_list: [...state.song_list, state.new_song],
}
```

I forgot to add the `...state`